# instantiate UIPicker with uitextfield string

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I am trying to pass my UItextfield value over to a UIPicker that I have loading in a alertview I'm just not sure what functions are available to me to get the values back into the picker?

At a guess I should be doing something in my

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pv == pickerViewA) {
        return 10;
    }
    else
        return 16;
}
```

but looking at the developers notes their is not much info about the UIPickerViewDataSource other than returning number of rows...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other data source and delegates as-

```
//for title of a row in a component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

//for width of a componenet
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component

//for row height of a component
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component

//for number of components 
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

for more info look at documentation -
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of the following two delegates to add data content to UIPickerView

– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:

– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:

For the first one u can return any NSString object and you cannot customize anything like font size or color for that.
But if you use the second one you can add the data content as a view to UIPickerView which can be achieved using a  UILabel and here you can customize the view as you require.

Hope this might help you

Happy coding !